# Showing Data Multiple Times In ListView

Tags: java, android

i am adding data to list view it shows multiple Times .

I have two Activities.first activity i have add button and listview . when i click add button i goes to second activity.in second activity,adding data to ArrayList.here i am passing arraylist object to first Activity using parcelable .

in first activity,here i am storing the getting ArrayList object values in one Arraylist<>.and then passing  object to listview. in listview data showing in multipule times .please go though this link https://www.codota.com/codebox/#/9lqy1ardnfyctyb9/shared

please, sorry i am not good in english.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
    ImageView addView, searchView;
    DetailsEmp detailsEmp = new DetailsEmp();
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Employee> listDetails=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    DetailsAdapter detailsAdapter;



@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Employee emp = (Employee) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(detailsEmp.PAR_KEY);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    addView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addImage);
    addView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsEmp.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } 
    }); 

    if (emp != null) {
        Employee emplyoee=new Employee();
        { 
            emplyoee.setName(emp.getName());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setCmpny(emp.getCmpny());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setDisig(emp.getDisig());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setListAge(emp.getListAge());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setListGen(emp.getListGen());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setListExp(emp.getListExp());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);

        Log.d("bundle Size is ", "Emp Name is " + emp.getName());
        Log.d("bundle Size is ", "Emp Sex is " + emp.getListGen());
        Log.d("list Size is ", " ArrayList<Emplyoee> " + listDetails.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < listDetails.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("list Size is ", " ArrayList<Emplyoee> "
                        + listDetails.get(i).getName().toString());
            } 
        } 

        detailsAdapter=new DetailsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listDetails);
        listView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);
    } 
} 
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true; 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will 
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long 
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml. 
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true; 
    } 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} 
} 

// second activity 
public class DetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Employee> listDetails;

public DetailsAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<Employee> listDetails) {
    super(context, resource, listDetails);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    this.context = context;
    this.listDetails = listDetails;
} 
private class ViewHolder 
{ 
    TextView empName,empCmpny,empDisig,empAge,empExp ;
    ImageView empIcon;
} 
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    ViewHolder holder=null;
    Employee emplyoee=getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null)
    { 
        convertView =inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, parent, false);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.empName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listName);
        holder.empCmpny=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCmpny);
        holder.empDisig=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listDesignation);
        holder.empIcon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.female);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    for (int j = 0; j < listDetails.size(); j++) {
        holder.empName.setText(emplyoee.getName());
        holder.empCmpny.setText(emplyoee.getCmpny());
        holder.empDisig.setText(emplyoee.getDisig());
        if (emplyoee.getListGen().toString() == "Male") {
            holder.empIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.client_male_dark);
        } 
    } 

    return convertView;
} 

} 

// POJO class 
public class Employee implements Parcelable {
String listName = null;
String listCmpny = null;
String listDisig = null;
String listExp = null;
String listAge = null;
String listGen = null;

public String getName() {
    return listName;
} 

public String getListExp() {
    return listExp;
} 

public void setListExp(String listExp) {
    this.listExp = listExp;
} 

public String getListAge() {
    return listAge;
} 

public void setListAge(String listAge) {
    this.listAge = listAge;
} 

public String getListGen() {
    return listGen;
} 

public void setListGen(String listGen) {
    this.listGen = listGen;
} 

public void setName(String listName) {
    this.listName = listName;
} 

public String getCmpny() {
    return listCmpny;
} 

public void setCmpny(String listCmpny) {
    this.listCmpny = listCmpny;
} 

public String getDisig() {
    return listDisig;
} 

public void setDisig(String listDisig) {
    this.listDisig = listDisig;
} 

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Creator() {

    @Override 
    public Employee createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.listName = source.readString();
        emp.listCmpny = source.readString();
        emp.listDisig = source.readString();
        emp.listAge = source.readString();
        emp.listGen = source.readString();
        emp.listExp = source.readString();
        return emp;
    } 

    public Employee[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Employee[size];
    } 
}; 

@Override 
public int describeContents() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    return 0; 
} 

@Override 
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    dest.writeString(listName);
    dest.writeString(listCmpny);
    dest.writeString(listDisig);
    dest.writeString(listAge);
    dest.writeString(listGen);
    dest.writeString(listExp);
} 
} 
// DetailsEmp 
public class DetailsEmp extends Activity {
    public final static String PAR_KEY="key_par";
    private EditText empName, empCmpny, empDisig, empAge, empExp;
    private RadioGroup empGender;
    private RadioButton empMale, empFemale;
    Button save;
    ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
@Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_emp);

        // getting the details from the xml 

        empName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        empCmpny = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCmpny);
        empDisig = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDisignation);
        empAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        empExp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editExp);
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 



                empGenderDetails(); 

            } 
        }); 

    } 

    protected void empGenderDetails() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        // empMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male); 
        Employee emp = new Employee(); 
        emp.setName(empName.getText().toString()); 
        //list.add(emp); 
        emp.setCmpny(empCmpny.getText().toString()); 
        //list.add(emp); 
        emp.setDisig(empDisig.getText().toString()); 
        //list.add(emp); 
        emp.setListAge(empAge.getText().toString()); 
        //list.add(emp); 
        emp.setListExp(empExp.getText().toString()); 
        //list.add(emp); 

        empFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female); 
        empGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup); 
        int sel = empGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); 
        empMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(sel); 
        emp.setListGen(empMale.getText().toString()); 
        Log.d("Employee data ", " Emp " + emp.listName.toString() 
                + empMale.getText().toString() 
                + empExp.getText().toString()); 
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                MainActivity.class); 
        Bundle b=new Bundle(); 
        b.putParcelable(PAR_KEY , emp); 
        i.putExtras(b); 
        //setResult(RESULT_OK, i); 
        startActivity(i); 
        finish(); 
        //list.add(emp); 
        Log.d("Emplyooe Size ","Emplyoee " + emp.getName()); 
        /* 
}
```

Comment: hi karthika, i posted a link please go through link https://www.codota.com/codebox/#/9lqy1ardnfyctyb9/shared

Comment: call `list.clear()` before adding new data to it.

Comment: hi dit,i need to save the data in array list .  what we enter.

Comment: Post DetailsEmp code also.

Comment: Ragavendra,please go through this link https://www.codota.com/codebox/#/9lqy1ardnfyctyb9/shared

Comment: Hi Ragavendra, i updated DetilsEmp please go through the code

Answer (score 2):

```
            emplyoee.setName(emp.getName());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setCmpny(emp.getCmpny());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setDisig(emp.getDisig());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setListAge(emp.getListAge());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setListGen(emp.getListGen());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
            emplyoee.setListExp(emp.getListExp());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
```

you keep adding a new emplyoee (mispelled btw, but that's up to you), you need to do

```
            emplyoee.setName(emp.getName());

            emplyoee.setCmpny(emp.getCmpny());

            emplyoee.setDisig(emp.getDisig());

            emplyoee.setListAge(emp.getListAge());

            emplyoee.setListGen(emp.getListGen());

            emplyoee.setListExp(emp.getListExp());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);
```

or:

```
 addView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

            emplyoee.setName(emp.getName());

            emplyoee.setCmpny(emp.getCmpny());

            emplyoee.setDisig(emp.getDisig());

            emplyoee.setListAge(emp.getListAge());

            emplyoee.setListGen(emp.getListGen());

            emplyoee.setListExp(emp.getListExp());
            listDetails.add(emplyoee);


             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsEmp.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } 
        });
```

Comment: Hi Nuadu,Thanks it's working.but i am Entering multipule input values  times how to sore in Arraylist.but,i my code only one data is showing in listview when i am entering multipule times.

Comment: Hi Nuadu,Thanks it's working.but when i Enter values fist time it showing in list view . Again i Enter values Second time .first  time  values are erased .i want to store first time values also.

Comment: detailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() needs to be called when you are adding or removing from the list I believe

Comment: which bit of the code you posted is the code for the button?

Comment: addView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addImage);
  addView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
   @Override 
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsEmp.class);
    startActivity(i);
 
   } 
  });

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't all of the adding to the list code be inside the onClick? at the moment you are only adding things to the list when your View is created, not when the button is clicked

Comment: only thing i can think of is that your Details adapter is being remade everytime, so maybe have it so like you do if(detailsAdapter != null){ detailsAdapter = new adapter... etc}, just a thought.. but that shouldn't affect the list as you aren't remaking that, does the Log show all of the Employees or does the list also get reset with only second entry?

Answer (score 0):

Your way of using Adapter is quite a immature one. Please On click of the save button add your "emp" object to the ArrayList and don't recreate the adapter once again when your dataset is changed just notify it the data has changed. Have a method as given below in your adapter rather then having the data supply in the constructor.

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Employee> _listOfEmp){
  this.listOfEmp = _listOfEmp;
}
```

and then notify the adapter in your activity when ever you change the dataset.

For your clarity.
Read this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

and see this example:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Hi Vishal, i am not getting what you saying.could u Explain Detail.